# How to properly loop and create json using database records in php

Tags: php

Am Trying to create a JSON array by leveraging info three database tables.

After leveraging info and solution found here [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864371/json-from-two-mysql-tables-in-php)
I came to realize that i have to use foreign keys for references and also use join queries.

The three tables is created as follows each with their reference keys

```
Create table categorys(id int primary key auto_increment, category_name varchar(30), buyer_userid int(30));

Create table product(id int primary key auto_increment, product_name varchar(30), buyer_userid int(30),category_id int,
foreign key (category_id) references categorys(id));


Create table sales(items_id int primary key auto_increment, item_name varchar(30),quantity varchar(30), buyer_userid int(30),
product_id int, foreign key (product_id) references product(id));
```

**Here is my expected JSON Format...**

```
[
{"id":"1","cat_name":"Provision","catbuy_userid":"100",
"products_info":[{"productid":"2","product_name":"Malt","buyer_userid":"100",
"sales_Info":[{"items_id":"1","item_name":"malt","buyer_userid":"100","quantity":"72"}]
}]},
{"id":"2","cat_name":"Cosmetics","catbuy_userid":"200",
"products_info":[{"productid":"3","product_name":"soapy","buyer_userid":"200",
"sales_Info":[{"items_id":"2","item_name":"cream","buyer_userid":"200","quantity":"83"}]
}]}
]
```

Here is the my coding so far

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = "mydb"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

    $res_arr = array();
$query = '
    SELECT 
c.id,
c.category_name,
c.buyer_userid,
p.id,
p.product_name,
p.buyer_userid,
p.category_id,
s.items_id,
s.item_name,
s.quantity
    FROM `categorys` c
        INNER JOIN `product` p ON c.id=p.category_id
        INNER JOIN `sales` s ON p.id=s.product_id
    ORDER BY c.id';

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    
       
        $res_arr[] = $row;
}
    echo json_encode($res_arr);
    exit;

?>
```

**Here is my json output**

```
[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"Provisions","category_name":"Provisions","2":"100","buyer_userid":"100","3":"4","4":"Malt","product_name":"Malt","5":"100","6":"1","category_id":"1","7":"4","items_id":"4","8":"malt","item_name":"malt","9":"93","quantity":"93"},
{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"Cosmetics","category_name":"Cosmetics","2":"200","buyer_userid":"200","3":"3","4":"soapy","product_name":"soapy","5":"200","6":"2","category_id":"2","7":"3","items_id":"3","8":"cream","item_name":"cream","9":"83","quantity":"83"}
]
```

Please how do I loop to get result as per json format above.

**Updated Section**

**Error warning Sample** They are so many error warnings when i run the code. below is just few of them

> Warning: Use of undefined constant products_info - assumed 'products_info' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\test.php on line 51

> Warning: Use of undefined constant product_name - assumed 'product_name' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\test.php on line 51

Comment: Sir Martin Left Join is given the same json output. I just want the result to be in the expected format above. between thanks

Comment: my answer does not match the output exactly... but the whole nesting is not required. it would only be required, eg. if there was more than 1 item per category (which won't ever happen, with a single query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have midified your php code so you can get your desired output.

Instead of assignind rows returned from mysql query create assosiative array as per your requirement and then convert to json

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = "mydb"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

    $res_arr = array();
$query = '
    SELECT 
c.id,
c.category_name,
c.buyer_userid,
p.id,
p.product_name,
p.buyer_userid,
p.category_id,
s.items_id,
s.item_name,
s.quantity
    FROM `categorys` c
        INNER JOIN `product` p ON c.id=p.category_id
        INNER JOIN `sales` s ON p.id=s.product_id
    ORDER BY c.id';

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    

        $res['id'] = $row[0];
        $res['cat_name'] = $row[1];
        $res['catbuy_userid'] = $row[2];
        $res['products_info']['id'] = $row[3];

        $res['products_info']['productid'] = $row[4];
        $res['products_info']['product_name'] = $row[5];
        $res['products_info']['buyer_userid'] = $row[6];

        $res['products_info']['sales_info']['items_id'] = $row[7];
        $res['products_info']['sales_info']['items_name'] = $row[8];
        $res['products_info']['sales_info']['buyer_userid'] = $row[6];
        $res['products_info']['sales_info']['quantity'] = $row[9];

        $res_arr[] = $res;
  }

}
  echo json_encode($res_arr);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sachin, Your solution is working though it does not actually gives the desire output properly. Am concerned about the error it shows. Please can you see updated section of my post for those error warnings. Thanks

Comment: Enclose all keys in single quote or double quote.  I forgot to enclose them

Answer (score 0):

When you say get results do you mean you want to access those values? If so, assign your json data to a variable say `data`.

Then:
    `$json = json_decode($data);`

```
foreach($json[0] as $values1) {
    var_dump($values1);
}

foreach($json[1] as $values2) {
    var_dump($values2);
}
```

To get product name for example from the first object you would then do $values1->product_name. And so on for the other properties.

Comment: Edited to show PHP version. You would need to decode it first then loop

Answer (score 0):

This be accomplished by casting from `(array) $row` to `(object) $row`:

```
$res_arr = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){    
    array_push($res_arr, (object) $row);
}
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
die(json_encode($res_arr));
```

I'd use [fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to prevent these duplicate numbered fields, which just bloat the payload... the whole nesting is basically useless and it only produces rubbish code quality, while there nowhere is more than a single nested item (and this is subsequently more complicated than necessary to access on the client-side). Nesting would make sense, when eg. first fetching all `categories` and then nesting all the `products` for that `category`, before proceeding with the next one `category`.