# Json from two mysql tables in PHP using Object

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to create a JSON output from those to tables to look like this:

I am trying to build a json output from two related MySQL tables. I have a table of "Restaurants" and table "Dishes" each item in Restaurants table has several relative items in the Dishes table which are referenced by id. Each Restaurant item ID is a foreign key in the Dishes table as f_id.

```
{
"Restaurants": [
    {
        "name": "String content",
        "misc info": "String content"
        "Dishes": [
            {
                "dish": "String content",
                "description": "String content"

            },
            {
                "dish": "String content",
                "description": "String content"
            }
        ],

    },
    {
        "name": "String content",
        "misc info": "String content"
        "Dishes": [
            {
                "dish": "String content",
                "description": "String content"
            },
            {
                "dish": "String content",
                "description": "String content"
            }
        ],

    }
]
```

}

Comment: You should provide information (schema) of your tables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864371/json-from-two-mysql-tables-in-php

Comment: Dear Connections I try to past two weeks till now can't get the result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json from two mysql tables in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864371/json-from-two-mysql-tables-in-php)

Comment: yeah! but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864371/json-from-two-mysql-tables-in-php have some confusions